# What is the maximum voltage and current audio sockets of a phone can withstand without damaging the phone?

Tags: audio, oscilloscope, diy

I want to make an oscilloscope which can measure signals of any voltage upto 50V. Is it possible to make a circuit which can do this safely without damaging my smartphone?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use your phone as an oscilloscope? If so, I think you will find that creating an app for this will be a challenging task.

Comment: @Henros:  Not terribly challenging, depending on your specifications.  Audio range, no DC, no problem.  Outside of **that** range, and it will be difficult.  I have a program on my phone with an oscilloscope display.  It just reads the microphone input.  Plug in an adapter with appropriate attenuation an protection circuits into the microphone port and you have an oscillscope.  A very limited one, but still an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 2):

A typical smart phone only has a microphone input.  You are limited to the signal levels that a typical microphone would produce.

The basic limits are:

- AC only.  Microphone inputs aren't made to deal with DC.
- Frequency range up to about 20 kHz.  Microphone inputs are only intended for use with audio signals.
- Low voltage input signals only.  Microphones only produces a few tens of millivolts.  The phone microphone inputs are designed to work with the low level signals from a microphone.

Current is not a problem.  Oscilloscopes normally have very high impedance inputs - they draw next to no current from the circuit you are examining.

Voltage is the interesting part.

You will have to reduce the voltage level to something that your phone can deal with.

As an example, you could use the following attenuator to reduce 50V peak to peak to 50 millivolts peak to peak:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgBmRT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Keep in mind that if you connect the ground clip to a high voltage then the housing (if metallic) and any exposed metal parts will be at high voltage - you phone could kill you.

You could write your own software, or you could download "PhyPhox."  It has (among many other things) an oscilloscope view of the microphone input (under "Acoustics/Audio Scope.")

Phyphox is not calibrated - the display is referenced to full scale (-1 to 1.)  For looking at things, it's probably good enough.  It won't do for measurements, though.

If you write your own software, you'll have to make sure to pick up the audio without the automatic gain control.  I don't know how you do that in Android.

With a fixed gain (or no gain) on the input, your software could include a calibration value that you can use to convert from "relative to full scale" to volts.

Comment: If you're interested mainly in frequency rather than level/waveform, I'd go straight to a spectrum analyser app, but I have a pocket scope

Comment: @ChrisH:  PhyPhox has a spectrum analyser as well.

Comment: I'll have to have a look then.